# ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'payable'

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, address.transfer, payable, truffle-compile

```solidity
function getWinners() public onlyOwner {
    require (now > endQuiztime, 'Quiz did not end ');
    require (isReveal, "You didnt reveal Questions");

    // calculate winner for each ques based on timestamp and add prize
    uint winner = 0;
    uint i;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        uint prev = 2**256 - 1;
        for(uint j = 1; j <= numPlayers; j++) {
            if(answers[i] == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(Players[j].choice[i],secret)) && Players[j].timestamp < prev) {
                prev = Players[j].timestamp;
                winner = j;
            }
        }
        if(winner > 0) {
            uint prize = (3 * quizFee * numPlayers) / 16;
            pendingAmount[Players[winner].account] += prize;
        }
    }
    // transfer remaining pending balance to them
    for(i = 1; i <= numPlayers; i++) {
        uint amount = pendingAmount[Players[i].account];
        emit Collected(Players[i].account, amount);

        if(amount > 0) {
            pendingAmount[Players[i].account] = 0;
            Players[i].account.payable(amount);
        }
    }
    // send contract balance to owner;
    selfdestruct(owner);
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Please reformulate your post to make it clearer for people to answer. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You'll also likely want to include enough code to allow other users to attempt to compile it. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a misuse of the `payable` keyword.

```
Players[i].account.payable(amount);
```

We don't have enough code to know where `Players[]` came from, but possibly something like:

```
address[] payable public players;
```

or in a struct

```
struct myStruct {
  address payable account;
}
```

Unrelated to `payable`, you'll want to watch out for scalability issues because you're using unbounded `for` loops. Something to be aware of before you get too invested in your structure: https://blog.b9lab.com/getting-loopy-with-solidity-1d51794622ad

Hope it helps.